# Why Arduino Pro IDE is not open source?

Tags: arduino-ide

I just found the alpha version of Arduino Pro IDE and I was wondering why this project is not open source as the classic IDE.

I didn't found anything about that online.

Comment: https://github.com/arduino/arduino-pro-ide/blob/master/README.md#user-feedback-and-issue-report

Comment: It appears that they intend to open-source the project but that the developers may not have reached the point where they believe that would be useful.  If you are wanting to contribute to the project you might send them a request.